# How to get this ggplot legend to be same order as bars?

Tags: r, ggplot2

The data and code I am trying to use:

```
library(ggplot2)

case_counts <- c(1800, 2064,  7118,  8697,  8737, 10738, 13602, 15007,15781, 17221, 17735, 18535, 19827, 20042, 22632, 25542,28920)
phenotpyes <- c("Known or suspected fetal abnormality affecting management of mother" ,
                "Cardiac and circulatory congenital anomalies","Viral infection" ,
                "Disorder of skin and subcutaneous tissue NOS" ,"Allergies other" ,"Cataract",
                "Other anemias" ,"Cancer suspected or other" ,"Other symptoms/disorders or the urinary system" ,
                "Pain","Abdominal pain" ,"Mood disorders","Other symptoms of respiratory system" ,
                "Diseases of esophagus" ,"Disorders of lipoid metabolism" ,"Pain in joint" ,"Hypertension")
categories <- c("pregnancy complications" ,"congenital anomalies" ,"infectious diseases" ,"dermatologic"
                ,"injuries & poisonings" ,"sense organs" ,"hematopoietic" ,
                "neoplasms" ,"genitourinary" ,"neurological" ,"symptoms" ,"mental disorders" ,
                "respiratory" ,"digestive" ,"endocrine/metabolic" ,"musculoskeletal" ,"circulatory system")

data <- data.frame(case_count=case_counts,
                   phenotype=phenotpyes,
                   category=categories)

data$phenotype <- factor(data$phenotype , levels = data$phenotype)
p <-ggplot(data=data, aes(x = phenotype, y = case_count,fill = category)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
p <- p + coord_flip()
p <- p + labs(x='phenotype', y='number of cases', fill='category')
p <- p + scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,30000,by=5000),limits = c(0,30000))
p
```

The plot it produces:

[image]

How do I get the legend to follow the same order as the bars from top to bottom: red, blue, green etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP here, figured it out:

```
library(ggplot2)

case_counts <- c(1800, 2064,  7118,  8697,  8737, 10738, 13602, 15007,15781, 17221, 17735, 18535, 19827, 20042, 22632, 25542,28920)
phenotpyes <- c("Known or suspected fetal abnormality affecting management of mother" ,
                "Cardiac and circulatory congenital anomalies","Viral infection" ,
                "Disorder of skin and subcutaneous tissue NOS" ,"Allergies other" ,"Cataract",
                "Other anemias" ,"Cancer suspected or other" ,"Other symptoms/disorders or the urinary system" ,
                "Pain","Abdominal pain" ,"Mood disorders","Other symptoms of respiratory system" ,
                "Diseases of esophagus" ,"Disorders of lipoid metabolism" ,"Pain in joint" ,"Hypertension")
categories <- c("pregnancy complications" ,"congenital anomalies" ,"infectious diseases" ,"dermatologic"
                ,"injuries & poisonings" ,"sense organs" ,"hematopoietic" ,
                "neoplasms" ,"genitourinary" ,"neurological" ,"symptoms" ,"mental disorders" ,
                "respiratory" ,"digestive" ,"endocrine/metabolic" ,"musculoskeletal" ,"circulatory system")

data <- data.frame(case_count=case_counts,
                   phenotype=phenotpyes,
                   category=categories)

data$phenotype <- factor(data$phenotype , levels = data$phenotype)
p <-ggplot(data=data, aes(x = phenotype, y = case_count,fill = category)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
p <- p + coord_flip()
p <- p +scale_fill_discrete(breaks=rev(data$category))
p <- p + labs(x='phenotype', y='number of cases', fill='category')
p <- p + scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,30000,by=5000),limits = c(0,30000))
p
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can i.e. specify the factor levels for categories in the order you want.

Update the lines in which you create the graph, leave the rest unchanged.

```
p <-ggplot(data=data, aes(x = phenotype, y = case_count,fill = factor(category, levels = rev(categories)))) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

[image]